# How to get an App version state history information from App Store Connect API

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

Is there a way to use App Store Connect API to get the information we see listed under Version History page in App Store Connect website?

Site URL: [https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/{app_id}/appstore/activity/ios/versions?m=](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/%7Bapp_id%7D/appstore/activity/ios/versions?m=)

[image: iOS App Store Versions]

I noticed that the website uses the following endpoints to retrieve that information:

```
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/{app_id}/stateHistory?platform=ios

https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/{app_id}/versions/{version_id}/stateHistory?platform=ios
```

This looks to be an internal only API.

Thanks!

Comment: You need [this endpoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/list_all_app_store_versions_for_an_app) with [this authentication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests)